# Usage of 消す in this context?

Tags: meaning, usage, verbs

My question is that can 消す be used for wanting to get rid of something? For example, "I really need to get rid of this weird feeling." この変な感じはどうしても消さないと。

Is 消す an acceptable verb to use here or is there a better word to use, like 拭う? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is natural to say この変な感じを消す, and probably more natural than 変な感じを拭う.

感じ and 消す are commonly used words and their register is close to colloquial. 拭う is more formal and more often used in phrases like ..という印象を拭{ぬぐ}えない (*the impression that... persists*).

Comment: Could 捨てる also work?

Comment: @user3856370 Yes. But I feel those phrases tend to be used in the negative - 感じを消せない/拭えない etc. 捨てられない is possible, but sometimes it has a positive connotation (can't throw away=need to cherish), and 変な感じを捨てられない by itself sounds like 変な感じ is positive, which makes it a little odd.